# C# Comment Template

Tags: c#, ghostdoc, autocommenting

Would anyone happen to know if you can make a custom template for comments in c#? I use a modification of the RME style of commenting instead of the  section.  Unfortunately, I don't have a ghost doc pro subscription.

I would like it to work just like visual studio where I type '///' and it creates the template of the comment.  I have seen similar questions saying you can't do this but they date form 2010 and it seemed to be a highly requested feature.

Comment: You could create a snippet that inserts comments like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use snippets to create source file headers and a comment snippet to add a line comment to the bottom of the header.

I am sure you could make a snippet that inserts whatever you want after ///

Snippets allows you to enter information through input boxes you can set up but if you are looking for something equivalent to GhostDoc where it fills in everything for you, I don't think that functionality is there.

Comment: Thanks.  For now it seems this and Ghostdoc are the only way.